# JavaScript SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when setting Grunt tasks

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs

I'm trying to set up a couple of tasks for Grunt but there seems to be an error that I can't find. JSlint points out to the watch section with the following error:

> Unexpected token, expected ,

While in the terminal I get:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

```js
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    sass: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          style: 'expanded',
          sourcemap: 'none'
        },
        files: {
          'compiled/style.css':'sass/style.scss'
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'compressed',
          sourcemap: 'none'
        },
        files: {
          'compiled/style-min.css': 'sass/style.scss'
        }
      }
    }

     watch: {
       css: {
         files: '**/*.scss',
         tasks: ['sass']
       }
     }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

Comment: I think there should be a comma "," between ```sass: {...}``` and ```watch: {...}``` tasks

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing a comma before Watch.

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
  grunt.initConfig({

    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

    sass: {
      dev: {
        options: {
          style: 'expanded',
          sourcemap: 'none'
        },
        files: {
          'compiled/style.css':'sass/style.scss'
        }
      },
      dist: {
        options: {
          style: 'compressed',
          sourcemap: 'none'
        },
        files: {
          'compiled/style-min.css': 'sass/style.scss'
        }
      }
    },

     watch: {
       css: {
         files: '**/*.scss',
         tasks: ['sass']
       }
     }

  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.registerTask('default',['watch']);
}
```

Hope this helps